# How to track down sql dump error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I track down this dump error? 
And most important, which process is causing it? 
What are the consequences?
It happens almost every weekend:

See sql dump output below:

```
*Current time is 23:26:40 11/05/17.                                                                               
=====================================================================                                            
       BugCheck Dump                                                                                             
=====================================================================                                            

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server                                                                   
version 13.0.4446.0                                                                                              
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,                                               
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and                                                
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.                                       


Computer type is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698B v3 @ 2.00GHz.                                                     
Bios Version is VRTUAL - 5001223                                                                                 
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698B v3 @ 2.00GHz                                                                       
4 X64 level 8664, 10 Mhz processor (s).                                                                          
Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 CSD .                                                                                  

Memory                               
MemoryLoad = 96%                     
Total Physical = 32767 MB            
Available Physical = 994 MB          
Total Page File = 39679 MB           
Available Page File = 5602 MB        
Total Virtual = 134217727 MB         
Available Virtual = 134132460 MB     
**Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x000001DE6E277240                                                                
***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0006.txt  
* *******************************************************************************                                
*                                                                                                                
* BEGIN STACK DUMP:                                                                                              
*   11/05/17 23:26:40 spid 38                                                                                    
*                                                                                                                
* Latch timeout                                                                                                  
*                                                                                                                
*                                                                                                                
* *******************************************************************************                                
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                
* Short Stack Dump*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [SQL Server Diagnostics (Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55516) available as an extension from SSMS 17.1 onwards to check for any potential causes and any available resolutions

After installing you will find a screen like below and after uploading dump, you can find potential solutions or patches which may help you.Ensure you upload DUMP to a location near to you

[image]

You also can load the dump using windbg and play with it if you have right symbols..Further event logs can show you more info

Most of the times Stackdumps are dumped due to bugs..Best way to proceed with them is to raise a ticket with microsoft.

Comment: FWIW, this feature was disabled by Microsoft back in 2018 due to privacy concerns (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview).

Answer (score 0):

Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minu
tes 6 seconds.  Internal database snapshot has split point LSN = 00014377:000000a5:0001 and first LSN = 00014377:
000000a3:0001.

**repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (master.**

**Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000022824F95600

You nee check dump file where stack dump detail provides.
We are sharing small piece of code for analysis.